# Make a basic auth client authenticate on a digest auth proxy server

Tags: networking, proxy, authentication, squid, digest

My company has a legacy application which needs to connect to the Internet.

Unfortunately, our network staff has changed the proxy settings in order to accept digest authentication only, which this application **doesn't** support.

Is there any way to setup a middle layer which interfaces between these authentication methods?

```
Legacy ---> (interface, maybe another proxy) ---> Digest Auth Proxy (squid).
```

Both application and proxy (squid) run on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use BurpSuite to connect legacy applications that do not support Digest authentication.

In BurpSuite, I run a proxy server with Basic authentication which in turn relay my actual traffic to my Upstream proxy server.

Legacy ---> **BurpSuite** ---> Digest Auth Proxy (squid).